# need to make online magazine with flip effect using scribd_carrierwave plugin in rails2.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scribd

Hi can anyone please help me to solve scribd carrierwave problem. i am using rails **2.3.11** version and integrated **scribd_carrierwave** plugin in that.all i want now is i just want to make the view look like **online magazine**.it should give effect like page flip and user can zoom in /out. finally i want thumbnail view of their entire pdf document.

kindly help me to accomplish this..........

refer the follow http://devaldi.com/zine/NZ_Tourism_2007.php?ro=flash,html

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the implementation, the `display_ipaper`-function takes an options hash. The corresponding options are listed over at [the scribd javascript API](http://www.scribd.com/developers/javascript_api#parameters). There is an option called `mode` which allows the "book" display-mode.

Try calling `<%= attachment.display_ipaper({mode: "book"}) %>` in your view. This requires the flash-view of the scribd-document, which seems to be the view which this gem uses.

Comment: thanks for your reply.i got book like view but i need to make this as flip view ,like we open any book. how is that possible please help me..